# Please tell me about startup account for Azure

Tags: .net, asp.net, azure

Guys, 
    Can you please tell me that ,I wants to learn Azure , by creating one - two 
sample Application, then is there any free account category on Microsoft azure portal ?
So that I can decide whether to go for Azure or remain stayed with Amazon EC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start here ['Getting Started with Windows Azure'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsazure/ff798116.aspx)

> Get a Paid Account Important
>
> To sign up for a Windows Azure
>   account, you will need to enter your
>   credit card information, but your
>   credit card will not be charged a fee
>   until you deploy an application.
>
> To deploy your application, you must
>   obtain a Windows Azure account. 
>   Windows Azure accounts come in the
>   form of an online subscription. You
>   can subscribe to Windows Azure by
>   visiting the Windows Azure Developer
>   Portal.
>
> For a current list of special offers,
>   see the latest Windows Azure Platform
>   offers and promotions.
>
> If you do not currently have a Windows
>   Azure subscription and just want to
>   evaluate the service,  sign up for the
>   Pay as you Go plan. There may be other
>   promotional offers available that
>   provide better value, so be sure to
>   check out the other offers before
>   subscribing. To subscribe, you will
>   need a Windows Live ID and a credit
>   card.
>
> If you are a current MSDN subscriber,
>   a special introductory offer provides
>   750 hours per month of compute
>   instance time for the first 8 months.
>   In addition, it provides a 5% discount
>   off the standard usage rates. For more
>   information, see Windows Azure
>   Platform Benefits for MSDN
>   Subscribers. Next Steps

Comment: Thanks Dude, it means there is nothing of the type 'trial' on Azure. Just like Google App Engine where we can make some demo apps free for limited hours. Thank you very much for giving me answer in simple words.

Comment: Not my words dude! Straight from the MS website.

Comment: There are occasional free offers, such as AzurePassUSA.cloudapp.net (which is currently not available). You should also check out the BizSpark program (www.microsoft.com/BizSpark) - if you qualify, you'll get an Azure account just like the MSDN Premium offer (750 compute-hours monthly, etc.).